# How to use image link for html webpage from application.yaml file in spring boot thymlef

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two environment, and having different link for a image.

**application.yaml**

```
image
   url: prod-env-link
```

**application-dev.yaml**

```
image 
   url: prod-env-link
```

How can we use the image link in html webpage in spring boot thymeleaf to pick the image based on environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img th:src="image-link" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming image.url is a URL and not a path to an image in the src/main/resources/static project folder you would obtain the image as follows:

```
<img th:src="${@environment.getProperty('image.url')}"/>
```

If image.url is a path to an image in src/main/resources/static you would use:

```
<img th:src="@{${@environment.getProperty('image.url')}}"/>
```